# Can't get Tomcat to start in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

Trying to help a friend get Eclipse and Tomcat configured but we are getting the error 'Starting Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost' has encountered a problem.

The error goes on to say "The Apache Tomcat installation at this directory is version 6.0.37.  A Tomcat installation is expected.

Not sure why this is because when we first went in to add Tomcat we choose to download version 7.

Thanks to anyone looking at this.

Comment: delete your tomcat from Eclipse and from the physical location (so 2 places) in your hard-drive and reinstall from Eclipse.

Comment: Download tomcat 6.0 again for jdk 1.6 . If you are using jdk 1.7 download tomcat 7.0